# Google API Autocomplete SearchBox - HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-api-java-client

I have very limited knowledge of HTML/JavaScript and have only just successfully managed to implement the Google Place Autocomplete Searchbox (without map) on my website.

I need two inputs that use the Google Place Autocomplete, but the following code that I am using, does not show the two input fields, just the second one (searchTextField2).

Can anyone please offer some advice, or point me in the right direction where I am going wrong with this code?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>

<style>
#searchTextField {
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
z-index: 4;
height: 40px;
width: 360px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 500;
color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
padding: 0px 4px;
transition: border-color 200ms ease, box-shadow 200ms ease;
box-shadow: none;
  }

#searchTextField2 {
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
z-index: 4;
height: 40px;
width: 360px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 500;
color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
padding: 0px 4px;
transition: border-color 200ms ease, box-shadow 200ms ease;
box-shadow: none;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Pick-up Address" tabindex=2><br>
<input id="searchTextField2" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Destination" tabindex=3>


<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField2');
var options = {
   // types: ['(cities)'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}//UK
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are re-declaring `var input` in your current code.

```
function initMap() {
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var input2 = document.getElementById('searchTextField2');
var options = {
   // types: ['(cities)'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}//UK
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2,options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul :-)